# Cannot find spacing button

Tags: mesh, vertices

I know there exists a spacing button in Blender (seen it on YouTube) but can't find it. It automatically spaces selected vertices an even distance from each other. Ideal for getting a more regular Grid Fill .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That person probably used the space tool from the [LoopTools Addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/LoopTools).

[image]

To activate the LoopTools Addon, go to the User Preferences Window and find the Addon in the Addons tab (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> > Addons > Mesh > LoopTools), then Check the little checkbox on the right.

After selecting a bunch of verts, use the Space Tool from the *Tools Shelf* > *Tools tab* > *Looptools*, or via the Specials Menu (<kbd>W</kbd>) > *LoopTools* > *Space*.

[image]

Comment: @TavernSenses If the answer works for you please mark it as accepted. blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @TLousky How you display that fancy looking rainbow-like edge colors? Is it the matter of User Preferences settings or your scripting magic skills :) ?

Comment: @Gonzou LOL, the edges are simply green when not selected (User prefs > Themes > 3D view > Wire Edit > Hex color 42C291), instead of the usual (almost invisible) black. So when some verts are selected and some aren't, you get this nice gradient from green to orange.